# How can I see the emails address from marketing campaigns in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have sent some emailing campaigns form Marketing, at "Mass Mailings" at  details I have "Emails" button. When I click on it I have columns "Mail ID (tech)", "Message-ID", "Sent" and others. But I do cannot see the email to which I have sent.

How can I see the email, which I think is the most important information, because I cannot see which client has opened the email?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Ek Kosmos, You need to add some code to do so. Please apply following code to your repository.

**addons/mass_mailing/models/mass_mailing_stats.py**

```python
 def _compute_recipient(self, cr, uid, ids, field_names, arg, context=None):
        res = dict.fromkeys(ids, '')
        for stat in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            if not self.pool.get(stat.model):
                continue
            target = self.pool[stat.model].browse(cr, uid, stat.res_id, context=context)
            email = ''
            for email_field in ('email', 'email_from'):
                if email_field in target and target[email_field]:
                    email = ' <%s>' % target[email_field]
                    break
            res[stat.id] = '%s%s' % (target.display_name, email)
        return res
```

**in same file add into columns = {}**

```python
'recipient': fields.function(_compute_recipient, string='Recipient', type='char'),
```

then add into view

**addons/mass_mailing/views/mass_mailing.xml**

```xml
<field name="recipient"/>
```

Comment: Is ok if I modify directly in the module?

Comment: I mean that's your choice, If you want to create a new module then you need to inherit a model and put the above field and method into it, and inherit tree and form view and apply the above field in it. That's not a big deal. is it.?

Comment: For me is because I have not worked in py. Can you please explain me where exactly I need to insert `<field name="recipient"/>` in `mass_mailing.xml` because there are many tags there.

Comment: You have to add a <field> into following record tag 

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_mail_mail_statistics_tree"> and <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_mail_mail_statistics_form">

Comment: Now I have the following error : `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/mass_mailing/models/mass_mailing_stats.py", line 67, in MailMailStats
    'recipient': fields.function(_compute_recipient, string='Recipient', type='char'),
NameError: name '_compute_recipient' is not defined`

Comment: Did you inherit the model.? Can you share the file.? You have to write method before the field declaration.

Comment: Ok, no errors now but where I should see the email?

Comment: Go to the form view of mass_mailing campaign and then click on sent or any state button you will see in a list view. If it resolved please accept as answer. thanks.!

Comment: okay can you share me your views/mass_mailing.xml . I think you missed to add into form view. You have to add into two places one is tree view and another is form view.

Comment: Please copy this. http://pastebin.com/j6RkSfpS . You didnt add any field. Please Check my previous comments atleast I explained there.

Comment: Yes, I have added but at the end after the last field tag : `</field> <field name="recipient"/>` as you have not specified.